# Twig filters and quotes return

Tags: php, twig

I created simple Twig filter

```
class Twig_Extension_Form extends Twig_Extension{
public function getName() {
    return 'Form';
}

public function getFilters() {
    return [
        'fLabel'=>new Twig_Filter_Method($this,'label_filter')
    ];
}

public function getFunctions() {
    return [];
}

public function label_filter($string,$id=null,$class=null){
    return '<label'.(!is_null($id)&&is_string($id)?' id="'.$id.'"':null).(!is_null($class)&&is_string($class)?' class="'.$class.'"':null).'>'.$string.'</label>';
}}
```

Filter worked but when I display code in browser quotes are replace on entities. When I use echo instead return filter work fine.

I want use return because not always label schould be display immediately.

Comment: Try {{yourmethod() | raw}}

Comment: Thanks, with |raw work fine. But this is only one way to this efect? It's inconvenient in template use always filter|raw, function|raw.

Comment: I don't know, try to look in the doc if you can disabled escaping from twig for certain method

Comment: Thank, I find solve. 
`public function getFilters() {
        return [
            'fLabel'=>new Twig_Filter_Method($this,'label_filter',['is_safe'=>['html']])
        ];
    }`

Automatic disable escaping for this filter. Thank for help

Answer (score 5):

Problem solved

```
public function getFilters() {
    return [
        'fLabel'=>new Twig_Filter_Method($this,'label_filter',['is_safe'=>['html']])
    ];
}
```

Disable autoescape for this filter. Third parameter for `Twig_Filter_Method` is

`['is_safe'=>['html']]`

or

`array('is_safe'=>array('html'))` in PHP < 5.4.x

Thanks for hints. It was helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

yes, use the raw filter!

or if you want to disable autoescape globally you can do so in your config:

```
twig:
# ...
  autoescape: false
```

or more granulary in your template you can define this as a dedicated block of code

```
{% autoescape false %}
...
{% endautoescape %}
```

see here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/autoescape.html

Answer (score 0):

For everyone :

Use the [raw](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html) filter.

{{yourmethod() | raw}}